# two while loops in one page

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

can I have two while loops with same condition but different if statements in one page?

For instance:

```
$qtytoAdd = $rec_qty[$mat_key];

while($qtytoAdd > 0){
    if(($remBalance - $qtytoAdd) >= 0) {
    //do something
    $qtytoAdd = 0
    }else{
    //do something
    $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $remBalance
    }
}
```

And something like this:

```
while($qtytoAdd > 0){
    if(($reqRemBal- $qtytoAdd) >= 0) {
    //do something
    $qtytoAdd = 0
    }else{
    //do something
    $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $reqRemBal
    }
}
```

The `$qtytoAdd` variable is actually defined at beginning before the loops. What I'm trying to do is run both while loops at the same time with both `$qtytoAdd` of each while loops having the same values at first.

Comment: Did you try it? If so, what happened? If not, why?

Comment: Do you wish to accomplish running both at the same time? As it is right now, it is possible. However it'll run the first loop until the end first, then the next up.

Comment: do not exit before entering second loop.

Comment: I did. The second loop I think is not working.

Comment: why noy? but you need to save $qtytoAdd in another variable for one or both

Comment: How about you try first and come up with what was the result and where you got stuck, more constructive way I assume.

Comment: @TheDeadLike, yes.I want to run both while loops at the same time. But is that possible?

Comment: Put $qtytoAdd=InitializeVlue to beginning of every loop, or much better use for.

Comment: instead of saying yes; explain the question in detail in your post.

Comment: @chris Not in my knowledge. However, is there a reason for you to avoid using elseif? Also it would be better if you could explain what you want to achieve in a wider extent.

Comment: @TheDeadLike, I edited the question sir. Please check. :]

Answer (score 1):

Sure but if you have them one after each then to break the first one, you would either need to force a break or make `$qtytoAdd != 0`

If it is the latter than it would cause the second loop to not be executed.

If you explain what you are trying to do, there should be a more elegant way to do it.

---

I think what you are actually looking for is just this:

```
$qtytoAdd = $rec_qty[$mat_key];

while($qtytoAdd > 0){
    if(($remBalance - $qtytoAdd) >= 0) {
    //do something
    $qtytoAdd = 0
    }else{
    //do something
    $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $remBalance
    }
    //second block
    if(($reqRemBal- $qtytoAdd) >= 0) {
    //do something
    $qtytoAdd = 0
    }else{
    //do something
    $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $reqRemBal
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I break the loop sir?

Comment: @chris just simply 'break;' http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Answer (score 1):

Firstly instead of breaking the loops using `$qtytoAdd = 0` you can simply use `break` to completely break out of the loop or `continue` to skip to the next step in loop.

And then you can merge the the loops in this way:
    $qtytoAdd = $rec_qty[$mat_key];

```
while($qtytoAdd > 0){
    if (($remBalance - $qtytoAdd) >= 0 || ($reqRemBal- $qtytoAdd) >= 0) {
        // Do something
        break;
    }
    if (($remBalance - $qtytoAdd) < 0) {
        $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $remBalance
    } elseif (($reqRemBal- $qtytoAdd) < 0) {
        $qtytoAdd = $qtytoAdd - $reqRemBal
    }
}
```